# James Periodicity- like results

Tags: at.algebraic-topology

It follows from Freudenthal theorem that if $X_b^t$ is a path connected $CW$-complex with finite number of cells in each dimension, with bottom cell in dimension $b$ and top cell in dimension $t$ such that $t\leqslant 2b$, then up to homotopy equivalence $X$ admits at least one desuspension, $X\simeq \Sigma Y_{b-1}^{t-1}$ where $Y$ is a suitable $CW$-complex. Let me add that I take the epimorphism part of the Freudenthal theorem, coming from the epimorphism $\pi_{2n+1}S^{n+1}\to\pi_n^s$ into the account, so a desuspension of $X$, if it exists, may not be unique!

A much stronger result is available for truncated projective spaces $P_k^n=P^n/P^{k-1}$ where $P^n$ is the $n$-dimensional real projective space. For any positive integer $a$ there is a positive number $2^{\phi(a)}$, coming from Hurwitz–Radon–Eckmann theorem, providing a homeomorphism 
$$\Sigma^{2^{\phi(a)}}P_k^{k+a-1}\cong P_{k+2^{\phi(a)}}^{k+2^{\phi(a)}+a-1}$$
known as the James periodicity.

Now, my question is that if I take $X=P_k^n$ for suitably chosen $k$ and $n$ is there a way to see that if $X$ admits a desuspension implied by Freudenthal theorem as above then the number of desuspensions must be divisible by $4$ (due to the action of the Steenrod algebra)? What about the homeomorphism part of the result? Although, having a homeomorphism it is not a priority for me!

I am a little bit confused with the example of $P_3^5$ and similar ``edge'' cases. Either the conditions relating $t$ and $b$ are not right or $P_3^5$ is suspension of a space which is not a projective space. But, the latter possibility confuses me about construction of such a $CW$-complex using Hopf invariant one maps! I am just interested in the $2$-primary case for now!

**ADDED** I understand that there might be cases such as $P_3^4$ which should desuspend and it cannot be $4$th suspension of a space, so the question somehow considers `generic' cases whatever "generic" should be interpreted?!